# Air for iOS - StageVideo - index is out of range error

Tags: actionscript-3, video, air

When I was working with StageVideo in Flash Pro CS5 I always got the error:

> RangeError: Error #1125: The index 0 is out of range 0

It was solved by updating and using the debug player in Flash Pro, because the default SWF player (used when testing the movie) was not new enough to support StageVideo.

Now, I'm using Flash Pro CS6 to compile iOS apps using Adobe Air 3.4. It works great on my iPad, but I always get the same error when testing the Air app in my desktop machine, wether in debug mode or not.

Is it possible to get rid of this error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well the answer is simple. Adobe Air for desktop does not support StageVideo...

> The StageVideo class is not supported in the AIR desktop or extendedDesktop profiles.

http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/media/StageVideo.html

Comment: so how can you test it on your mac? not at all? do I always have to test it on my mobile?

Comment: The latest version of Air includes StageVideo for desktop